# BaseActionableDynamicQuery Upgrading to LiferayDXP

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I'm upgrading portlet from Liferay 6.2 to Liferay DXP.
I cannot find the `BaseActionableDynamicQuery` in Liferay 7 API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultActionableDynamicQuery` replaces in Liferay 7 the old `BaseActionableDynamicQuery` of Liferay 6.2

More info see source code here: 
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0.x/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/DefaultActionableDynamicQuery.java